# Scripting Geeqie Refresh

Tags: bash, gui

I've been searching the net quite some time but didn't find the way to refresh the folder that is open. The GUI just takes 'R' and all is fine. The same behaviour does not appear not be available through any call from a bash script.
I was trying to call the running instance of geeqie with -r and -l:/path/to/folder option like

```
geeqie -r -l:/home/user/Pictures
```

Terminal keeps prompting me to read into --remote-help that didn't help me.

Has anyone experiences controlling geeqie from command line.

Thanks in advance.
C.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best way ever of achieving the update functionality.

I am using a bash script checking every 2s for a new file in the specified folder. If there is, then call geeqie with remote option -r and file:/path/to/file option.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name=""
while true;
do
    new_name=$(ls -t /home/<user>/Pictures/_DSC* | head -1) # newest file in folder
    if ["$new_name" != "$file_name" ]
    then
        echo $file_name
        file_name=$(ls -t /home/<user>/Pictures/_DSC* | head -1)
        geeqie -r file:$file_name
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```